# UML binary association aggregatee has access to aggregator

Tags: uml, associations

Firstly, I'd like to thank those who answered my previous question ages ago. Currently I'm engaging more in the design phase UMLs, as this is my first medium scale deployment I'm entrusted with.

This is extremely simple, but it bugs me so.

If (Component) owns (Manager of Component), and (Manager of Component) has a reference to (Component) through which it manages it; how do you fully describe the relationship?

I know it is aggregative, but how do you describe (Manager of Component) possessing a reference/pointer to the (Component) that physically owns the (Manager of Component) ?

Example: Lidar owns a LidarManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On first sight, it seems a little strange for `Component` to own `Manager of Component`.  Would expect it the other way around.  Anyway, assuming you need it this way...

...it's just a plain old aggregation relationship, navigable in both directions, with diamond at `Component` end.

hth.

Comment: The regular aggregation relationship automatically denotes the visibility to its owner? From what I was told, it doesn't unless I use the vanilla binary relationship, but that's less specific. To clarify, I'm specifically asking how does representing an aggregation where "I own you and you can't see/access me" and "I own you and you can't see/access me" differ. I do agree that it's a strange setup, principle was to have the control scheme tunneled through the device to make the driver modular

Comment: No, navigability and aggregation are independent.  Specifically, in the UML metamodel, there's no constraint between `Association.navigableOwnedEnd` and `Property.aggregation`.

Comment: In that light is there a way to describe visibility in the aggregation? Or is this not handled by this relationship?

Comment: In UML terms "visibility" means navigability.  To show visually just draw the aggregation rel with no other adornments on the line (if you put an open arrowhead on the non-aggregate end, it means the association is only navigable from aggregate->aggregated).  Most UML tools provide checkboxes in the property sheet to set navigability for each end and will draw line appropriately.

Comment: Ah, manageability across associations was a skimmed topic in undergrad.. Thank you for the clarification, I'll have to revisit that section.